# What is causing this error, this project is fully functional on another server?

Tags: laravel, cpanel

I'm trying to set up this project on a server using cpanel, let's say the redirect and all that is working however when I try to see the page I get this error.

> Refused to apply style from 'http://page.com/css/app.css?id=4513b702e5714c4239c0' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

If I click on the link I get a 404 not found page? This exact project is installed on another server with cpanel and it's works fine, I don't know what I'm doing wrong? what can be causing this problem.

The page won't load at all it just stays loading forever.

The error I believe is coming from the app.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/loading.css') }}">

    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="{{ asset('img/favicon.png') }}"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('/css/fontawesome.min.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('/css/solid.min.css') }}">
    <link href="{{ mix('/css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

    @inertia

    <div class="sk-cube-grid">
        <img src="{{ asset('img/favicon.png') }}" alt="logo loading">
    </div>
    <script src="{{ mix('/js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

on the final script

`<script src="{{ mix('/js/app.js') }}" defer></script>`

I'm not sure why the file is there

Comment: all the rest of the project works fine?

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia I can't tell because the first page is the login and I can't see anything without logging in

Answer (score 0):

Source: [Setting up a laravel project on a server with cpanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58864516/setting-up-a-laravel-project-on-a-server-with-cpanel)

You can try this add this file

> .htaccess file to public_html folder

```
RewriteEngine on 

# for example.com rewrite landing page to subdirectory/index.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ subdirectory/index.php[L]

# for example.com rewrite all other URIs to subdirectory/uri
# (?!subdirectory/) is a negative lookahead that stops rewrite then uri 
# already starts with /subdirectory/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?!subdirectory/)(.+)$ subdirectory/$1 [L,NC]
```

Change subdirectory to home and example to your domain name.

Comment: This isn't what I'm asking

Comment: all the other file of the project load with no problem? can you please post the header of the page with app.css on it?

Comment: The first thing to load is the login page, if I can't login I can't see any other part of the project

Comment: is the file linked as <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css"> ?

Comment: if the app.css file start with commets, take it out, if not, please post the begin of that file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202368/discussion-between-nancy-and-albertosinigaglia).